# Jquery to dynamically create table with increment div id

Tags: jquery, html, css

Currently i am using jquery to dynamically create a table with a div inside a cell.
Each div id will be incremental.

I am able to create the table and div, but the div are added into all the cell, what i wanted is for row 1, only 1 div is added to the first cell, for row 2, 1 div is added to row 2 cell 1 and cell 2 and so on.

Current Output is as follow: [current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCoTw.png)
Expected Output is as follow: [expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aaSq.png)

Final Output is as follow: [final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjBtu.png)

The code is as below

```js
var table = $('<table>').addClass('number');
for(i=1; i<4; i++){
    var row = $('<tr>').addClass('row-hr');
 for (c=1; c<4; c++)
 {
  var col = $('<td>').addClass('cell');
  row.append(col);
  var dre = $('<div id="row'+i+'btn'+c+'">').addClass('red').text('j ' + c);
  col.append(dre);

 }
    table.append(row);
}


$('#here_table').append(table);
```

```css
.number
{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-spacing: 0px!important;
}


.cell
{
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.cell:last-child
{
 border-right: 0px!important;
}

.red
{
 background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="here_table"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace your JQuery code with this one

```
var table = $('<table>').addClass('number');
for(i=1; i<4; i++){
    var row = $('<tr>').addClass('row-hr');
    for (c=1; c<4; c++)
    {
        var col = $('<td>').addClass('cell');
        row.append(col);
    if(c <= i ) {
        var dre = $('<div id="row'+i+'btn'+c+'">').addClass('red').text('j ' + c);
        col.append(dre);
    }

    }
    table.append(row);
}
$('#here_table').append(table);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forget to include the very last line of code. Now check out the result.

Comment: Hi Usman, need your advice again. If i intend to do the final output as shown in the above qns. How can i amend the code to achieve it?